# How to keep relative position of TImage as a Marker on a TImage background image

Tags: c++, c++builder-11-alexandria

I am trying to place a number of marker images onto a background image in C++Builder Alexandria 11.3. I can can create them and place them, but cannot keep them in the same position if I resize the image.

[Marker positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs8my.png)

EDIT: Removed previouse edit for clarityt...

http://www.mbp.bcbhelper.com

[Body diagram with markers added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2tf.png)

As mininmal code is needed here to demonstrate a problem I submit this code which is cut down to the max and, in my opinion, requires everything in the example to constitute minimal code, the code contains only the components that would be on you component pallet as they do on mine, please do look at problem and suggest a solution if yo can.

EDIT: Removed code, not relevant to question

@Remy, refer to your last comment this

```
NewMarkerX = OldMarkerX * (NewImageWidth / OldImageWidth);
NewMarkerY = OldMarkerY * (NewImageHeight / OldImageHeight);
```

is the same as this, where m[i]->X = is same as NewMarkerX

```
for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
    {
    //DrawnMarkerX = (OriginalMarkerX * DrawnImageWidth) / OriginalImageWidth;
    //DrawnMarkerY = (OriginalMarkerY * DrawnImageHeight) / OriginalImageHeight;

    //DrawnMarkerX = (m[i]->X * newImageWidth ) / oldImageWidth;
    //DrawnMarkerY = (m[i]->Y * newImageHeight ) / oldImageHeight;

    m[i]->X = (m[i]->X * newImageWidth ) / oldImageWidth;
    m[i]->Y = (m[i]->Y * newImageHeight ) / oldImageHeight;

    //SetBkMode(Canvas->Handle, TRANSPARENT);
    Canvas->TextOutW(m[i]->image->Left + 10, m[i]->image->Top + 10, IntToStr(m[i]->image->Left) + "," + IntToStr(m[i]->image->Top));
    Canvas->TextOutW(m[i]->image->Left + 10, m[i]->image->Top + 10, IntToStr(m[i]->image->Left) + "," + IntToStr(m[i]->image->Top));

    Canvas->TextOutW(50, 50, IntToStr((int)newImageWidth) + "," + IntToStr((int)newImageHeight));

    }
```

is this correct, if so it does not work, I have explored other possiblities though but will not go into those as they have been many.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

During a resize, you know the old and new sizes of the background image, so its quite easy to calculate new marker positions. Simply take the new image width divided by the old image width, and then multiply the marker's old X position by that value. Repeat for the image height and marker Y position:

```
NewMarkerX = OldMarkerX * (NewImageWidth / OldImageWidth);
NewMarkerY = OldMarkerY * (NewImageHeight / OldImageHeight);
```

Or:

```
NewMarkerX = (OldMarkerX * NewImageWidth) / OldImageWidth;
NewMarkerY = (OldMarkerY * NewImageHeight) / OldImageHeight;
```

The alternative is to not use manually positioned `TImage` controls at all.  Use `TPaintBox` instead.  In its `OnPaint` event, you can draw your background image first at the desired size, and then draw each marker at the appropriate position relative to that image size using similar formulas:

```
DrawnMarkerX = OriginalMarkerX * (DrawnImageWidth / OriginalImageWidth);
DrawnMarkerY = OriginalMarkerY * (DrawnImageHeight / OriginalImageHeight);
```

Or:

```
DrawnMarkerX = (OriginalMarkerX * DrawnImageWidth) / OriginalImageWidth;
DrawnMarkerY = (OriginalMarkerY * DrawnImageHeight) / OriginalImageHeight;
```

Comment: I get what you are saying and I was heading in that direction last night but was getting late so went to bed, what you have proposed is simple enough but not having done any work with TPaintBox, I am strugling to get an initial size that will fit the size of paint box but the image size is much bigger that the paint box size, I have looke maybe not hard enough but can seem to find how to resize for the paintbox via the TGraphic it's prob simple but I am not getting it (as usual)

Comment: @OutOfTime You don't have to resize the paintbox. If you are on Windows, use `box->Canvas->Handle` to get the native handle (same for the image) and use WinAPI functions for drawing. If the image data is always the same, you can keep the TImage on the form (Visible = False) and copy from it. `StretchBlt()` will draw the image while stretching it to the paint box canvas size. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt

Comment: You don't need to use the Win32 API directly. The PaintBox's `Canvas` has methods for drawing images with stretching. Just load the background image and markers into memory, and then draw them into the `Canvas` with the needed positions and sizes. You can zoom in and out of the PaintBox by simply stretching the drawings. Use the PaintBox's `Invalidate()` method to trigger a repaint, and then redraw using the updated position/size on the next `OnPaint` event.

Comment: Ok, the resize of image is working ok using an OnResize methode of a TPanel so at this point my interest is to reposition markers from database onto background image where the markers were first appied.  Using Remy's code did not do it for me, using the code in my edit portion of the OP keeps the markers in formation of where they were placed but not at the position relative to the image they were placed at, would you like to see the who form code, it may help.

Comment: @OutOfTime Look at my answer again, you are not using the formulas as I showed them. You are dividing by the wrong value. Also, you are using the PaintBox's width/height instead of the background image's width/height. They are not the same when zooming in/out of the image.

Comment: @OutOfTime You need a very simple ratio here. The X/Y distance on the original image in relation to the X/Y distance on the resized image. That is a very simple algebraic formula: `(a/b) = (c/d)`, where you set `a` as the X/Y coordinate on the original image, `b` as the original image width/height, `c` as the resized X/Y coordinate, and `d` as the resized image width/height, so just solve for `c`, eg: `a*d = b*c` == `c = (a*d) / b` Now just plug in values for `a`, `b`, and `d` to get the result of `c`, that will tell you where to put each marker. It is basic school math

Comment: Thanks Remy, I agree with what you say and it would have / be easy without my condition which I think you are aware of, if not, it is stage 4 terminal cancer which is into my bones affecting my spine and neuropathy, again, I am not looking for sympathy and I know ou understand, what was a lot easier is no a little harder bit I am closser to finishing my project to help the medical insdustry that has been indicated is badly needed go to http://mbp.bcbhelper.com/sample-page/. one thing I have realised is that I have not been zooming the image, it was simply resized according to align property

Comment: I set on the TPanel so not really doing any proper resize calcs, I will try and get my head around your latest reply  Cheers Remy (life is short, live it well)

Comment: @OutOfTime "*I have not been zooming the image, it was simply resized according to align property*" - the same principle applies.  You are scaling the image, so you just need the marker's coordinates on the original unscaled image to be the same proportion on the scaled image. So, if you know what the scaling factor is (by comparing the old and new image sizes), you can apply that scaling to the new marker coordinates to keep it in relative position

Comment: @Remy, getting back to my origional question, if you want to continue with me, just asking for clarification in the last 2 lines of your example, "DrawnMarkerX = (OriginalMarkerX * DrawnImageWidth) / OriginalImageWidth;"  can "DrawnImageWidth" be refered to newImageWidth and oldImageWidth

Comment: @OutOfTime sure, whatever. That just leads you back to the first example.